# Position UITableViewCell on Top when Cell is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want that the selected cell will always be at the top most position of `tableView`.
I can to it via:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

but my problem is, when the number of cells, for example, is just 3. When I select cell number 3, it just stays there. Was that the normal behaviour? If yes, then, can you suggest something so that I can achieve my goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U can use `contentInset` and `setContentOffset` property of tableview for example

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    CGFloat height = 44.0f;//cell height
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, height * indexPath.row, 0);

   //[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES]; //commenting u are setting it by using setContentOffset so dont use this
    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (indexPath.row * height) )animated:YES]; //set the selected cell to top
}
```

hope this helps u .. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in the *didSelectRowAtIndexPath* delegate of table view

```
CGFloat height = 44.0f;//cell height
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, height * indexPath.row, 0);

[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (indexPath.row * height) )animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set `UITableView` content offset using

```
[tableView setContentOffset:offsetPoint animated:YES];
```

or

```
[tableView setContentOffset:offsetPoint];
```

and get your selected cell position by

`CGPoint offsetPoint = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame.origin`

then you can move cell to your desired offset as bellow

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    float topOffset = 64; //in case of navigationbar
    CGPoint offsetPoint = CGPointMake(0, cell.frame.origin.y - topOffset);
    [tableView setContentOffset:offsetPoint animated:YES];

}
```